# How to add bottom margin for the last card in the listview?

Tags: flutter

How to add bottom margin for the last card in the listview? Currently there is no gap between bottom screen line and the last card in the listview.

The listview is placed right in the body section.

```
ListView.builder(
    itemCount: favorites.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Card(
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20).copyWith(top: 20), ... ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add bottom padding to `ListView.builder` i.e

```
padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10)
```

Answer (score 2):

For adding margin to last card u can apply condition when its last card give margin for eg 15 else when false then 4

```
ListView.builder(
      itemCount: list.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        print(index);
        return Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(
              left: 4,
              bottom: list.length - 1 == index ? 15 : 4,
              right: 4,
              top: 4),
          child: ListTile(
            tileColor: Colors.grey,
            title: Text(list[index].toString()),
          ),
        );
      })
```